# Why does this code typecheck correctly with flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a function returning a less specific type, being called by something returning a more specific type. See the link here [tryflow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgZgNg9g7iwCgEBcCeAHApgAgMoEsBbdCTAeQCMArTAY2WwF5sBvAbQGdkAnfAOwDmAXQBc2PgFdCFTNwC+SNFjzpaTVhzGTpshQjAS+9fFD7YwUKAAoAlGILFSlGvVYJs2bpmQTuZlvhiAIwADHIA3Ah6BkbIJmYUAIbctvaqbh5ePn7mlraRckA)

`

```
/*flow*/

type SimpleObject = {[string]: number}

type Spc = {s: number}

function foo(): SimpleObject {
  return {i: 10};
}

function bar(): Spc {
  return foo();
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `Spc` is a *specification* of `SimpleObject` since `{s: number}` fits perfectly within the wider type. Flow allows you to return more specific types, so that may be the cause of the problem.

See: https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/

Also note:

> In Flow, it is considered safe to pass an object with extra properties where a normal object type is expected.
>
> https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types
>
> When an object type has an indexer property, property accesses are assumed to have the annotated type, even if the object does not have a value in that slot at runtime. It is the programmer’s responsibility to ensure the access is safe, as with arrays.
>
> https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps

#### Explanation [from the flow github issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7120):

Your function bar typechecks because the ~equivalent implementation

```
function bar() {
  const result = foo();
  return {s: result.s};
}
```

also typechecks. As you note in your Stack Overflow answer, this is
because indexer property access is unsound.

In other words, `SimpleObject` and `Spc` are subtypes of each other(!):

```
// @flow
type SimpleObject = {[string]: number}
type Spc = {s: number}

declare var a: SimpleObject;
(a: Spc);  // OK

declare var b: Spc;
(b: SimpleObject);  // OK
```

This is obviously unsound, but it seems consistent with the rest of Flow.